# install methods for mod_wsgi and apache

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I plan to deploy a django app on apache. After having set up apache ,python and django on the dev box,i was going through the tutorials for configuring mod_wsgi. I see that there are two methods-

- Installation into Apache
- Installation into Python

How do they differ?Apart from the obvious difference that file location will be different,what are the other differences? Going forward,what are the implications of each?

> FYI, I do not have any issue with installing/configuring mod_wsgi with
>   apache. I am just interested in understanding the
>   implications/differences between installing into python and installing
>   into apache.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi
FYI,i do not have any issue with installation.I just wanted the difference between installing into python and installing into apache.